# How to make flyspell bypass some words by context?

Tags: emacs, emacs23, flyspell

I use Emacs for writing most of my writings. I write using reStructuredText, and then transform them to LaTeX after some preprocessing since I write my citations á-la LaTeX. This is an excerpt of one of my texts (in Spanish):

```
En \cite[pp.~XXVIII--XXIX]{Crnkovic2002} se brindan algunos riesgos
que se pueden asumir con el desarrollo basado en componentes, los
```

This text is processed by some custom scripts that deals with the `\cite` part so `rst2latex` can do its job.

When I activate flyspell-mode it signals most of the citation keys as spelling errors.

How can I tell flyspell not to spellcheck things within `\cite` commands.

Furthermore, how can I combine rst-mode and flyspell, so that rst-mode would keep flyspell from spellchecking the following?

- reST comments
- reST code literal
- reST directive parameters and arguments
- reST raw directive contents

Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can set the variable `ispell-parser` to the value `'tex` so that flyspell will ignore (la)tex sequences. To do so, you can either set it manually in each buffer like so:

```
M-: (setq 'ispell-parser 'tex)
```

or you write a little function that will do that for you. Put the following in your .emacs file:

```
(defun flyspell-ignore-tex ()
  (interactive)
  (set (make-variable-buffer-local 'ispell-parser) 'tex))
```

Then you can still invoke it manually, using

```
M-x flyspell-ignore-tex
```

or you could add a hook that calls that function automatically whenever you edit a file of a certain type. You would do the latter by adding the newly defined function to your `auto-mode-alist`. Say your filenames typically end with ".rst", then add this line to your .emacs file:

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.rst$" . flyspell-ignore-tex))
```

As for the second part of your question: making flyspell-mode ignore larger regions, such as, e.g., reST comments, is not easily achievable. It becomes clear when you think about the way flyspell works: it checks text on a word-by-word basis. For that, `flyspell-word` only looks at one word at a time which it sends to an ispell process running in the background. The ispell process does the dictionary lookup and returns whether or not the current word is correct. If `flyspell-word` had to check every single time whether or not the current word is part of a comment or other region that should not be checked, it would be rather slow, because that would include quite a bit of searching through the buffer.

Now of course, one could approach this a little bit smarter and first find the non-comment regions etc. and then do the word-by-word checking only in those parts that are outside of those regions - but unfortunately, that's not the way flyspell is implemented.

If you can do without the "fly" part, however, ispell-mode has a mechanism to customize which regions of a buffer can be skipped. This is done via the variable `ispell-skip-region-alist`. But although flyspell-mode works off ispell-mode, for the reasons outlined above that variable is not used by flyspell-mode.

Comment: Thomas, thanks a lot! I have used ispell-mode in the past, but flyspell suits me better at the moment. Nevertheless, after reading the `ispell-skip-region-alist` doc, I think I would have to program a function to detect the end of the comment. I'm not that familiar with Emacs Lisp yet. 

Anyway the `ispell-parser` way is still helpfull. Maybe I could check how its used and create my own ispell-parser tweek when I can.

Comment: Manu, you probably won't have to program a lisp function to detect the beginning and end of a comment. Typically a regular expression should be enough, one that matches the beginning and one that matches the end. You put both of them in parenthesis and add it to the `ispell-skip-region-alist` (I tried it out yesterday, it's actually not that difficult) and there's a good chance that `rst-mode` already contains the regexps you're looking for somewhere.

Comment: In reStructuredText the end of the code section is detected when the indentation level is decreased. So regexp would't help. Best regards, Manu.

Comment: Although for \cite it may help.

Comment: What should I do if I am using `aspell` instead like (`(setq ispell-program-name "aspell")`)? @Thomas

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `flyspell-generic-check-word-predicate` as I explained [in this question](https://superuser.com/questions/345084/how-to-exclude-in-flyspell-mode-and-flyspell-buffer/345461#345461) at Super User.

Answer (score 1):

(aspell's tex filter may do exactly what you want - but if you want a more general solution)

Although I am using the code below to persuade flyspell to not flag certain words with numbers in them,
you can use this sort of hook to match certain context.

looking-at starts at the position you want - so you may want to search backwards for start/end of whatever context you care about.

```
(when "another attempt to accept certain words flyspell/ispell/aspell flags as incorrect"
  (defun flyspell-ignore-WordNumber99-stuff/ag (beg end info)
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char beg)
      (cond
    ((or
       (looking-at "\\bWord1\\b")
       (looking-at "\\bWord99Foo\\b")
       )
      t)
    (t nil)
    )
      )
    )
  )

(add-hook 'flyspell-incorrect-hook 'flyspell-ignore-WordNumber99-stuff/ag)
```